# MongoDB' sort() method does not work with name field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

when i use sort( { name : 1 } ), it should give result in ascending order of name But
reverse happened , i got result in descending order
[image]

And when i use sort( { name : -1 } ), it should give result in descending order but it gave in ascending order
[image]

But it worked fine with address fields, this problem occur only with name field .

```
var mongodbClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

mongodbClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbase = db.db("mydemodb");

    dbase.collection("customer").find().sort({ name: 1 }).toArray((err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(res);
    });
```